# Node.Js prompt user input

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server-2008

I'm creating a desktop application that talks to SQL Server for MAC users using Node.JS.

Is it possible in Node.JS to take the input from the user and display the data from SQL server based on user input?

For example, in the code below, can I put an input box `onload` and allow user to input `customercode` and display `InvoiceNumber` and `customername`.

Also, will I be able to run the below code on MAC?

@Serger B,

I followed the link you suggested and was successfully able to connect to SQL Server. How can I add a user prompt to enter the customerCode for the below code? Also, it would be great is someone could help me running the script from the browser.

```
var sql = require('mssql'); 

var config = {
user: 'temp',
password: 'test123',
server: 'laptop\\localDB', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
database: 'AVTemp01',


}

var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
// ... error checks

// Query

var request = new sql.Request(connection); // or: var request = connection.request();
request.query('select top 5 companycode from invoiceheader', function(err, recordset) {
    // ... error checks

    console.dir(recordset);
});

// Stored Procedure

var request = new sql.Request(connection);
request.input('input_parameter', sql.Int, 10);
request.output('output_parameter', sql.VarChar(50));
request.execute('procedure_name', function(err, recordsets, returnValue) {
    // ... error checks

    console.dir(recordsets);
});

});
```

Comment: Matthew, Can you please help me with the above question. I would appreciate your inputs on this. Stuck with this issue for long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this module to access the SQL server: https://www.npmjs.org/package/mssql
We use it successfully in our projects. 
The quick example on the project homepage just shows it all.

And I don't see anything preventing you to do it on Mac.

Comment: Sergey- Can you give me hand how to implement the above code using the  link you suggested? I'm new to Node.JS. I appreciate your response

Comment: Can somebody please help? Can't find any sample node.js code. Thanks

Comment: @Node.JSBeginner, can you explain how are you expecting to request the user for input? E.g. inside a web page or what? Since Node.js doesn't have any "traditional" user interaction built in, you'd have to build quite an infrastructure to capture user input: serve a page, accept a POST request from a form, send a response. The webpage iteslf needs some coding etc.
I don't quite get what are you expecting to get.

Comment: I'm trying to create a desktop application; when user clicks the application, input box will pop up and user can enter customercode. I didn't know that Node.js don't have any user interaction built in. Is there any other option you could think of?

Comment: The most straightforward way is to serve a small web app. A more desktop-like approach would be to use some project like [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) , but the latter is definitely not the beginner path. Another option is to use command line arguments, but I guess that's not your bet.